# Insert row with fixed background color into JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am making a simple app which displays the current time and date to JTable but with fixed color background to each row (INSERTED TO TOP OF TABLE). I have trouble setting a fix color background to the row as it changes or the assigned color does not fuse with the data. When new data was inserted, the background was left at first row while the data supposedly be there moved down. How can I fix this?

```
    package testJava;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.SystemColor;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

    public class tableApp extends JFrame {

        private JPanel contentPane;
        private JTable table;
        DefaultTableModel model;
        int counter;
        /**
         * Launch the application.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        tableApp frame = new tableApp();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Create the frame.
         */
        public tableApp() {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);
            counter = 0;
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
            scrollPane.setBounds(21, 24, 392, 227);
            contentPane.add(scrollPane);

            table = new JTable();
            scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

            setActiveTable();
            startTmer();


        }
        public void startTmer(){

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      Random r = new Random();
                      int a = r.nextInt();
                      if ((a%2) == 0){
                          table.setBackground(Color.red);

                      }
                      else{
                          table.setBackground(Color.blue);
                      }
                      model.insertRow(0, new String[]{"Test : " + getDateandTime()});
                    counter++;  
                  }
                }, 2000, 2000);     
        }


        private void setActiveTable(){
            model = new DefaultTableModel() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                       //all cells false
                       return false;
                    }
            };
            String[] columns = new String[]{"test"};
         model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);
        table.setModel(model);

             TableColumnModel colModel=table.getColumnModel();
             colModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(300);    

             Font font = new Font("",1,14);
             table.setFont(font);
             table.setRowHeight(16);
        }

        public String getDateandTime(){
            String res = "";
            LocalDateTime myDateObj = LocalDateTime.now();
            DateTimeFormatter myFormatObj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String formattedDate = myDateObj.format(myFormatObj);

            res = formattedDate.toString();
            return res;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You'll need a `TableCellRenderer` for that. To clarify: When you insert a row `"RowA"` at index 0 with the color RED, and then insert a row `"RowB"` at index 0 with the color GREEN, then the table should show `"RowA"` as the *second* row, and it should be RED (i.e. it should keep the color that it had when it was added), right?

Comment: yes ,exactly. However when I use TableCellRenderer, it change the color of whole table which is not what I want . I need to assign fix color for each value of the cell as I insert new data.

Comment: When using a table cell renderer, you have to look up the color that the respective row should have. **ROUGHLY** with something like `getCellRendererComponent(...int row...) { ... setBackground(colorFor(row)); }`, where `colorFor(row)` provides the color that the row should have. If that doesn't help, maybe I can post an [MCVE] as an answer, but it's probably nearly a duplicate of other questions...